# Proving guess wrong used for substitution method

Tags: analysis, algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, substitution

Following is my recurrence relation :

$T(n) = 2T(n−1) + c_1$. Complexity: $O(2^N)$.

I want to prove it by substitution method/ mathematical induction
(You can get insight of it from : http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/recitations/24/using-the-substitution-and-master-method.html)

Now even if I am making guess: $T(n) = kn-b$
then also I am able to prove $T(n) = O(n)$, which is obviously wrong.

Can anyone prove, why it is wrong ?

P.S. I know we can solve it by other methods.
I want to know how we get to know , our guess is wrong.

Comment: Where the guess $T(n)=kn-b$ comes from? If you set $c_1=0$ for now, you'll see that $T(n)$ will *double* on each step, cannot be "linear".

Comment: How exactly can you prove that $T(n) = kn - b$ can possibly work? Are you making assumptions about the exact value of $c_1$? It seems like the best you can do in that direction is something like to set $T(0) = 1$ and $c_1 = -1$. But that doesn't give you a non-trivial linear formula for $T(n)$, it's constant.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you with poor question !
@A.G.  Yes I get that now.
Constant is getting double each time and does not remain same.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $T(n)=kn-b$

Then $T(n+1)=kn+k-b$

Inserting the reccurence relation gives $$kn+k-b=2kn-2b+c_1$$ for all $n$.

Both sides are linear functions depending on $n$. If both sides would be equal FOR ALL n,
the linear coefficients would have to be the same. But $k\ne 2k$

What about $k=0$ ? In this case, we get $c_1=b$. Therefore, only constant
sequences are possible with the given guess.

So, the guess must be wrong, except for constant sequences.

Comment: It should be possible to get arbitrary constant sequences from the relation too, where the constant value depends on $c_1$. See my comment to the original post.

Comment: Sorry, missed the $2$ at the term $2b$ on the right side and got to a false result.

Comment: no problem, I like your line of analysis for the problem. I just alluded to it in a vague comment post but you made it absolute in your answer. +1, friend. =)

Comment: @Peter : I got that after posting question, deduce similar equation like you. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(0)=T_0$ and iterate
\begin{align}
T(1)&=2T_0+c_1,\\
T(2)&=2T(1)+c_1=2(2T_0+c_1)+c_1=2^2T_0+(2+1)c_1,\\
T(3)&=2T(2)+c_1=2(2^2T_0+(2+1)c_1)+c_1=2^3T_0+(2^2+2+1)c_1,\\
\vdots\\
T(n)&=2^nT_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k\cdot c_1=2^nT_0+(2^n-1)c_1=2^n(T_0+c_1)-c_1.
\end{align}
One particular constant solution is for $T_0=-c_1$. All others have growth as $O(2^n)$.